# Using Java and Apache POI customizing image size within excel cell

Tags: java, file-io, apache-poi, xls

i am using apache poi to extract certain data in xls format. The cell size of each column has been fixed.

Now my data is being fetched to each respective cell perfectly,but i want to change the scale of my image being fetched in one cell.

I want to change the scaling of the image to lets say height 12% and width 16% only without altering the cell size.

my code:

```
ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = givenSetForExcel.getMetaData();
int columnCount = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet(this.reportName);

int pictureIdx = 0;
if (substr.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg")
    || substr.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")) {
            pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(bytes,
            Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
} else if (substr.equalsIgnoreCase("png")) {
            pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(bytes,
            Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
}
try {
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        dataCell.setCellValue("");
        break;
    }

CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
Drawing drawing = spreadsheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
// fit picture
ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
anchor.setCol1(i);
anchor.setRow1(rowCounter);
anchor.setCol2(i + 1);
anchor.setRow2(rowCounter + 1);
row.setHeight((short) 600);
drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
```

Comment: Please post the code that you've already tried.

Comment: Why are you inserting images into Excel?  Are you generating some sort of printable report?

Comment: yes,i want to generating some sort of printable report.